# Checking if plane ticket price contains airport departure fee

Tags: air-travel, fees-and-charges, uruguay, montevideo

I'm planning to fly Brazil - Montevideo (Uruguay) - Brazil next month. When departing from Montevideo there's a [44 USD](http://www.aeropuertodecarrasco.com.uy/tasa-de-embarque/ct_11/en/) departure fee (according to various other sources which seem outdated it may be [31 USD](http://www.uruguaynow.com/entry_requirements.php), [29 USD](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g294323-s301/Montevideo:Uruguay:Arriving.And.Departing.html) or [40 USD](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Montevideo)).

I've read that some airlines may include that fee in ticket price. Since I haven't bought the ticket yet and three airlines are offering similar prices, can I check in advance if any of them have the fee included? Or do I need to write to all the airlines and request this information?

Comment: Following your 44 USD link, the airport website states that it is included in the airfare price (albeit very poorly translated into English).  Therefore you can assume all three airlines will include it. The government dictates the method of collection and all airlines follow that policy.

Comment: @Tom +1 looks like an answer to me :-)

Comment: Yeah I agree, can you post it as an answer? There are too many websites I found claiming that "some" airlines have it included and some not so I think that might be useful :) Especially if you say it's always regulated by the government.

Comment: I just bought the ticket - the tax is indeed metntioned as part of the fare (138,50 BRL which is around 44 USD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read the Spanish version of the website, and it says the departure fee is indeed included in the airline fare.
I'd find rather unusual that some airlines include it and some others don't.

On the other hand, when buying the ticket, there's usually a link (just before you confirm your buy) that will show you the fare details. There you can confirm that the fee is included in your ticket price.